# How to rank entries (according to a field value) which are dynamically grouped by another field?

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

Given the following (toy model) tables:

Table1

```
Company Date        User    FK_Subject
A       10.05.2016  1       1
A       10.06.2016  1       2
A       10.07.2016  2       3
B       10.03.2016  1       4
B       10.04.2016  2       5
B       15.05.2016  1       6
```

Table2

```
PK_Subject  Subject_text
1           One
2           Two
3           Three
4           Four
5           Five
6           Six
```

There is a relation between primary key `PK_Subject`and foreign key `FK_Subject`.

I want to filter entries from Table1 displaying `Company` and `Subject_text` of only the most recent date given a `User` (or combination of `User`s).

For this I created a calculated column in Table1 called `[DateRank]` with the formula

```
=RANKX(FILTER(Table1; [Company]=EARLIER([Company]) && [User]=EARLIER([User])); [Date])
```

giving a new Table1

```
Company Date        User    FK_Subject  DateRank
A       10.05.2016  1       1           2
A       10.06.2016  1       2           1
A       10.07.2016  2       3           1
B       10.03.2016  1       4           2
B       10.04.2016  2       5           1
B       15.05.2016  1       6           1
```

I can create [this pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MK7K.png) which works as intended if you filter only a single user. When you keep a combination of users (in this toy-model case: all 2 of them), it shows two entries per company:

```
Company Date        Subject_text    Sum of FK_Subject
A       10.06.2016  Two             2
A       10.07.2016  Three           3
B       10.04.2016  Five            5
B       15.05.2016  Six             6
```

However, the desired output for both users selected would be the most recent entry taken over both users (i.e. the whole table):

```
Company Date        Subject_text    Sum of FK_Subject
A       10.07.2016  Three           3
B       15.05.2016  Six             6
```

As hinted in the text the solution should generalize to arbitrary many users and combinations thereof.